# Нужна ли запятая после "А" в предложении "А КАК ОБЪЯСНИТЬ - НЕ ЗНАЮ"?

Tags: пунктуация

> **А как** объяснить - не знаю!

Можно же так: "А не знаю, как объяснить".

Поэтому после "А" в "А КАК" нужна запятая. Правильно ли я понимаю?

А в этих предложениях (указаны ниже)?

> **А когда** он приедет - не пойму!

> **А зачем** он это сказал - непонятно!

> **А почему** он так себя ведёт - не могу объяснить!

Comment: Зачем ставить запятую между союзом и наречием? На основании какого правила?

Comment: И, если он приедет, мы всё поймём. Здесь же есть зпт. после "И". И мы всё поймём, если он приедет.

Comment: *Если* — не наречие, а союз.

Comment: Как же это всё сложно!

Comment: Сложно. Что поделать :) Только учить.

Answer (score 1):

1. ***А как объяснить — не знаю!***

В начале предложения находится **союз А**, его значение в этом случае можно посмотреть по словарю.

**Из словаря:** [http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=а&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B0&all=x)

**А, союз**. 4. (в начале вопросит. и восклиц. предл., в начале реплики или при внезапном переходе от одной мысли, темы к другой; обычно со сл.: как, какой, сколько и т.п.). **Употр. для усиления выразительности.** А знаешь, мама, о чём я думаю? А что говорят учёные? А как будет весело! А сколько таких поэтов?! Что с вами? — А ничего, слушаю.

2. ***А как объяснить — не знаю!***  Почему ставится тире.

Это сложноподчиненное предложение (ССП). Здесь придаточное предложение  стоит перед главным и отделяется от него тире. Постановка тире (а не запятой) связано со структурными особенностями этого предложения (инверсия придаточного при разной структуре предложения). В этом случае пауза и тире необходимы для понимания состава предложения.

3. Сравнить: ***А не знаю, как объяснить.***  Здесь инверсии нет, структура предложения ясна, поэтому достаточно запятой.

**Примечание.** Запятая — это основной знак в СПП, тире же является дополнительным знаком и используется при необходимости.

Comment: Полагаю, что союз А сохраняет свое связующее и сопоставительное (неявно выраженное) значение, хотя и приобретает дополнительное усилительное , свойственное частице. Возможно, есть и другие мнения по вашему вопросу, и наши участники примут активное участие в обсуждении. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Дополнение к ответу

**О союзе А в начале предложении**

Мы довольно часто употребляем союз А в начале предложения. В этом можно убедиться, просто наблюдая за собственной разговорной речью. Союз больше напоминает частицу или своеобразный связующий элемент между предложениями. **Но почему мы используем именно этот союз?**

По  классификации союз А относится к группе **противительных** союзов, но его основное значение – **сопоставительное**.  Например: *Он художник, а она студентка. Мне нравится классическая музыка, а моей подруге нет.* Здесь нет отрицания – мы просто **сравниваем и сопоставляем** различные ситуации и мнения.

Но что же мы сравниваем и сопоставляем в нашей устной речи, так часто употребляя этот союз?  Рассмотрим **примеры из словаря**:

*А знаешь, мама, о чём я думаю?*   Обсуждается какая-то тема, и к ней добавляется новое направление, которое нужно сопоставить со сказанным ранее.

*А что говорят учёные?*  Обсудили мнение людей разных профессий, и теперь речь дошла до ученых.

*А как будет весело!*  Сравнивались многие доводы за и против участия в вечеринке. Это положительный довод: весело же будет, надо пойти!

Ну и конечно, **такой союз-частица** запятой и паузой **не отделяется от предложения**, в том числе если в его начале стоит вопросительное слово.